# Windows 10 anniversary changing hwid

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-c++, hwid

Recently after the windows 10 anniversary update all my users who have updated to windows 10 anniversary had their hwid changed. They are still using the same machine. However users who haven't updated or are using windows 7 or 8 hwid havent changed.

This lead me to believe that it was the windows update that caused this issue.

The method I used to fetch and compare the hwid was this:

```
HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo;
if (GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo))
    printf("HWID: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
```

My question is their another method to hwid lock a program to a computer that will no suffer issues like the one above?

Comment: You want to "hwid lock" a program -- but you want to allow the program to work if the hwid changes? That doesn't make any sense, and you should think about what you really want instead. What *do* you want to lock your program to? What's allowed to change while continuing to allow your program to continue to run? What's not allowed to change? (I expect you will think and say "computer", but there's not even a "this is the same computer" definition that *people* use, so that's not good enough for an automated check.)

Comment: No, the question says "another method" to hwid lock a program. IE: Not using HW_Profile_info.

Comment: The hwid lock is compiled with program does not require internet connection. The hwid lock cannot be changed after being compiled.

Comment: Okay, if by "hwid" you mean something other than the hardware profile ID as returned by `GetCurrentHwProfile`, please explain what you mean by it.